# VBA for inputting checkmarks on Worksheet using Windings font

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a code for inserting checkmarks on Worksheet when user clicks right button on Worksheet in specific ranges.

[image]

This seems to work when file is on my computer. Then I open it from our File system and try to right click I receive an error:

[image]

Pointing to first `.Font.Name = "Wingdings"`

Excel file is opening on my computer, I am not on virtual machine or something. What is the problem out here?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5:F11, C13:F25, C27:F33, C35:F47, C49:F77, C79:F84, C86:F112, C115:F124, C126:F131, C133:F142, C144:F149")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If ActiveCell.Value = Chr(168) Then
            ActiveCell.ClearContents
            With ActiveCell
            .Font.Name = "Wingdings"
            .Value = Chr(254)
            .Font.Size = 16
            End With
        Else
            With ActiveCell
            .Font.Name = "Wingdings"
            .Value = Chr(168)
            .Font.Size = 16
            End With
        End If
        Cancel = True
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: try changing `Activecell` to `Target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on my system and couldn't replicate the error.

However, I first formatted the code and changed `ActiveCell` to `Target`.

Here is what I tried that worked fine:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5:F11, C13:F25, C27:F33, C35:F47, C49:F77, C79:F84, C86:F112, C115:F124, C126:F131, C133:F142, C144:F149")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        With Target
            If .Value = Chr(168) Then
                .ClearContents
                .Font.Name = "Wingdings"
                .Value = Chr(254)
                .Font.Size = 16
            Else
                .Font.Name = "Wingdings"
                .Value = Chr(168)
                .Font.Size = 16
            End If
        End With

        Cancel = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that the problem is in protection of my Worksheet. So when it is protected, checkbox can't been changed. Otherwise it works

Comment: What type of file type did you save it as? Might help to at least see if it has something to do with it. Also, have you tried testing this with a different font such as Arial? Does it work without the font in there? Just options to try to isolate the problem.

Comment: That makes sense. Glad you figured it out. Cheers!